# Qt style, Windows vs Xubuntu (GTK+) - no border in QGropBox

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, qt5

I'm starting to develop a Qt application in Xubuntu, in fact I started to develop it in Windows 7 and now I'm trying to move to Linux.

The thing is that the Graphical User Interface looks different here in Xubuntu, i.e. there in no border around `QGroupBox`.

If I understand it correctly, it seems difference comes from different styles adopted by `Qt` in different platforms (Qt is meant to look native, regardless of platform).

I've read [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/681/qgroupbox-borders/5) and [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/style-reference.html) and understood the issue might be related to GTK+, but still didn't got the entire point. Doing:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
app.setStyle("fusion");
```

helps but the issue is still there.

Is it possible no make the GUI identical in Windows and Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Before I start: Qt uses native APIs behind the scenes, which means all but two styles are not portable. This is okay because Qt *is meant to look native, regardless of platform*. Your groupbox looks funny coming from a Windows background, but to a Xubuntu user, it looks normal and correct.

To your question: Not in the sense you are hoping for. Two styles are completely cross-platform: `QWindowsStyle` (Windows classic look, like Win95-2000) and the recent `QFusionStyle`.

If you want your program to look exactly the same across platforms, setting both to use Fusion would work. Unfortunately, this would take away the native look for your application on Windows.

Comment: Some style key strings ("windowsxp", "windowsvista", "gtk" and "macintosh") are presented at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html. May I ask for a style key string that resembles Windows 7?

Comment: `QWindowsVistaStyle` is compatible with Vista and all later MS operating systems. It's used by default.

Comment: I'm digesting the truth of your answer. I looked around some XFCE apps trying to find similar GUI components to what I'm using. And I'm closing to conclude my design (in)hability should be taken into account.